# How to duplicate a Javascript on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, duplicates

I have some code for a stopwatch here: https://github.com/Aerodyll/Stopwatch

As you can see the counter changes the html of 4  tags for hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. And it ties to 3 buttons, start, stop and clear.

This works fine when there is just one counter on screen but how would I alter this code to make it work for multiple counters on the screen at once (that all work independently)? It just breaks when I duplicate it at the moment. I understand why it breaks because it is pointing to the same html objects but how would I go about duplicating the counters on the page without writing a whole new script for each one?

(I have found a couple of examples of other users doing this but their code is very difficult for me to understand.)

Comment: give an ID to each div containing the counter - Store those ID's inside an array in your JS - Loop over your array and do your stuff for each counter

Comment: Don't hardcode the ids of the HTML elements, make them a variable. Put the code into a function which accepts the name of the HTML element(s) as argument (and use it as said variable). Call the function multiple times with different arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> works fine when there is just one counter on screen but how would I
>   alter this code to make it work for multiple counters on the screen at
>   once ...

1. Wrap your HTML elements into a `div` to create multiple blocks. Give this wrapper an `id` if you want to target those individually. Alternatively, just give it a same `class` if you want to target them all.
2. Wrap your entire code into a function. This will encapsulate your logic.
3. Call that function with the element `id` or element itself.
4. Within the function get references to your `span`s within the element. This could be done via `class` or `nth-child` selector.

**Example:**

*The example below is your original code, just refactored as per the above points.*

```js
var allWatches = document.getElementsByClassName('stopwatch'), 
    firstWatch = document.getElementById('sw1')
;

// One way to call stopwatch on individual blocks
//stopWatch('sw1'); // pass id to the function

// Another way to call stopwatch on individual blocks
//stopWatch(firstWatch); // pass the element ref to the function

// One way to call stopwatch on all blocks
for(i=0; i < allWatches.length; i++) {
  stopWatch(allWatches[i]);
}

function stopWatch(element) {
  /* Declaring the html objects that will contain the time */
  var hrs, mins, secs;
  /* Declaring the html buttons */
  var start, stop, clear;
  /* Other variables */
  var seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0, t;
  // check if id is passed or the actual element reference
  if (typeof element === 'string') {
    element = document.getElementById(element);
  }
  // get reference to component elements inside
  hrs = element.querySelector('.hours');
  mins = element.querySelector('.minutes');
  secs = element.querySelector('.seconds');
  start = element.querySelector('.start');
  stop = element.querySelector('.stop');
  clear = element.querySelector('.clear');

  function runWatch() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
      seconds = 0; minutes++;
      if (minutes >= 60) {
        minutes = 0; hours++;
      }
    }

    /* Hours */
    if (hours == null) {
      hrs.textContent = "00";
    } else {
      hrs.textContent = hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours;
    }

    /* Minutes */
    if (minutes == null) {
      mins.textContent = "00";
    } else { 
      mins.textContent  = minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
    }

    /* Seconds */
    if (seconds == null) {
      secs.textContent = "00";
    } else { 
      secs.textContent  = seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
    }

    t = setTimeout(runWatch, 1000);

  } // End of runWatch
 
  runWatch();
 
  /* Start button */
  start.onclick = runWatch;

  /* Stop button */
  stop.onclick = function() { clearTimeout(t); }

  /* Clear button */
  clear.onclick = function() {
    hrs.textContentL = "00"; mins.textContent = "00"; secs.textContent = "00";
    clearTimeout(t);
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
  } 
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div.stopwatch {
  width: 180px; border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 8px; display: inline-block;
}
div.stopwatch > div { display: flex; margin: 8px; } 
div.stopwatch > div > * { flex: 1 1 auto; }
div.stopwatch > div > span { 
  text-align: center; 
  font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 1.7em;
}
div.stopwatch > div > button { 
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sw1" class="stopwatch">
  <div>
    <span class="hours">00</span>
    <span class="minutes">00</span>
    <span class="seconds">00</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="start">start</button>
    <button class="stop">stop</button>
    <button class="clear">clear</button> 
  </div>
</div>

<div id="sw2" class="stopwatch">
  <div>
    <span class="hours">00</span>
    <span class="minutes">00</span>
    <span class="seconds">00</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="start">start</button>
    <button class="stop">stop</button>
    <button class="clear">clear</button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, you've answered my questions and a few I didn't ask too. Really helpful, cheers.

Comment: Could I please ask for a few more minutes of your time to explain to me what is happening in the JS in lines 1-14 (including comments). I have been beating my head on this for a few hours tonight and while I sort of understand the separate parts of it I do not grasp how it comes together or what it is actually doing on the page. 

Thanks
Aero

Comment: @Aerodyll: There are several ways to target the elements. The first commented statement is an example of how you could just pass the `id` of the element to your function. Then within the function you use `getElementById` to get reference to that element. The second commented example shows how to first get the reference and pass that to the function. Within the function, then you use that reference directly. Third example (not commented) is the one being used in this answer. It simply gets a `nodeList` reference to all elements with the same className, iterate and call the function with each .

Answer (score 0):

If you'd want to have multiple instances of the stopwatch working you would obviously need more start stop buttons. You could call the function that adds time with a parameter that would be the button id. The button id would then tell the function to what stopwatch to add the time. Of course, the stopwatch needs to be defined by unique id as well so you can point to it :)

Good luck with the learning!